# Find high value transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table structure as below -

```
Account Number | Transaction Type | Amount | Date
```

Transaction type can be Credit or Debit. I need to check if either Credit or Debit transaction Amount is greater than some threshold value. If yes, check if the Amount is greater than Income * 10 (which is stored in some other table).

There could be multiple scenarios (Consider Credit threshold >= 10000, Debit Threshold >= 20000, Income = 1000) -

```
1. Account Number | Transaction Type | Amount | Date
   A1             | Credit           | 10000   | 11-11-2017
```

No Debit row exists in this example, but A1 satisfies all conditions

```
2. Account Number | Transaction Type | Amount | Date
   A2             | Debit            | 20000   | 12-11-2017
```

No Credit row exists in this example, but A2 satisfies all conditions

```
3. Account Number | Transaction Type | Amount | Date
   A3             | Credit           | 10000   | 13-11-2017
   A3             | Debit            | 5000    | 13-11-2017
```

Both Credit and Debit row exists in this example, but A3 satisfies Credit conditions

```
4. Account Number | Transaction Type | Amount | Date
   A4             | Credit           | 5000   | 14-11-2017
   A4             | Debit            | 20000  | 14-11-2017
```

Both Credit and Debit row exists in this example, but A4 satisfies Debit conditions

```
5. Account Number | Transaction Type | Amount | Date
   A5             | Credit           | 10000   | 15-11-2017
   A5             | Debit            | 20000   | 15-11-2017
```

Both Credit and Debit row exists in this example, but A5 should satisfy Debit condition, as it has greater value (max needs to be taken in this case)

```
6. Account Number | Transaction Type | Amount | Date
   A6             | Credit           | 10000   | 16-11-2017
   A6             | Debit            | 20000   | 16-11-2017
```

Consider Income = 3000 in this example, both Credit and Debit row exists in this example, but A6 should not satisfy any condition, as Income *10 is greater value than Credit/Debit transaction values.

I have already used UNION with LEFT & RIGHT joins to find both Credit/Debit values but finding if there is any better way to write this script. In case any Credit/Debit value do not exists, take it as zero. I am using SQL server 2012.

Script developed (on a high level) so far:

```
SELECT
temp.Number as Number,
temp.Amount1 as CrAmt,
temp.Amount2 as DrAmt
FROM
(
SELECT
    t1.Account_Number AS Number,
    t1.Amount AS Amount1,
    isnull(t2.Amount, 0) as Amount2
FROM
    TableName AS t1 WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT JOIN
    TableName AS t2 WITH (NOLOCK) on isnull(t2.Transaction_Type, 'Debit') = 'Debit' and isnull(t2.Account_Number,t1.Account_Number) = t1.Account_Number
WHERE
    t1.Transaction_Type = 'Credit'

UNION

SELECT
    t1.Account_Number AS Number,
    t1.Amount AS Amount1,
    isnull(t2.Amount, 0) as Amount2
FROM
    TableName AS t1 WITH (NOLOCK) RIGHT JOIN
    TableName AS t2 WITH (NOLOCK) on isnull(t2.Transaction_Type, 'Debit') = 'Debit' and isnull(t2.Account_Number,t1.Account_Number) = t1.Account_Number
WHERE
    t1.Transaction_Type = 'Credit'
) temp
where
(temp.Amount1 >= 10000 and temp.Amount1>= Income * 10) OR (temp.Amount2 >= 20000 and temp.Amount2>= Income * 10)
```

Comment: it will help it you provide the script

Comment: Yes added the script

Comment: I don't get your script fully yet, but I'm highly suspecting it's not optimal. Could you please examine this query & tell what faults are present in its output? `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE AccountNumber IN (SELECT DISTINCT AccountNumber FROM YourTable WHERE (TransactionType = 'Credit' AND Amount > @CreditThreshold AND Amount > @Income * 10) OR (TransactionType = 'Debit' AND Amount > @DebitThreshold AND Amount > @Income * 10))`

Comment: These would just give me Account Number, while I would want Debit and Credit transaction values and its dates all in a single row

Comment: FWIW, it starts with `SELECT * FROM YourTable`, which cannot give Account Number only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a cleaner approach

```
DECLARE @income       decimal(18, 2) = 1000*10,
        @CrThreshold  decimal(18, 2) = 10000,
        @DrThreshold  decimal(18, 2) = 20000

SELECT AccountNumber, CrAmt, DrAmt
FROM (
  SELECT AccountNumber, 
         CrAmt = SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionType = 'Credit' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END), 
         DrAmt = SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionType = 'Debit' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END)
  FROM TableName
  GROUP BY AccountNumber, [Date]) T
WHERE (CrAmt >= @CrThreshold AND CrAmt >= @income)
OR (DrAmt >= @DrThreshold AND DrAmt >= @income)
```

Comment: It will give me 2 rows for same Account if it has both Debit and Credit transactions wherein I just want a single row with both Debit, Credit values.

Comment: @Kabir did you test this before commenting?

Comment: Yes, after thorough testing, I commented this

Comment: @Kabir the only time this will give you 2 rows for the same account is if it appears in more than one date, which is not the case on your sample data

Comment: If you don't care about the date, then you can remove it from the `GROUP BY AccountNumber, [Date]`